# I have an issue with require 'yaml' ,anyone can shed any light?

Tags: ruby, yaml

This is my code:

```
require 'yaml'

class Person
    attr_accessor :name, :age
end

yaml_string = <<END_OF_DATA
---
-!ruby/object:Person
age: 45
name: Jimmy
- !ruby/object:Person
age:23
name: Laura Smith
END_OF_DATA

test_data = YAML::load(yaml_string)
puts test_data[0].name
puts test_data[1].name
```

This is the result I get:

> ruby yaml1.rb
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 4 (Psych::SyntaxError)
>       from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in`parse_stream'
>       from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
>       from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in`load'
>       from yaml1.rb:17:in `'
>   Exit code: 1

According to the book i'm reading (Beggining Ruby by Peter Cooper). My result should be like the one below:

```
Jimmy
Laura Smith
```

Anyone know why this is happening ? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

Your YAML is not formatted properly, I guess wrote it by hand. Here's a correct version

```
---
- !ruby/object:Person
  age: 45
  name: Jimmy
- !ruby/object:Person
  age: 23
  name: Laura Smith
```

In case you didn't spot the differences, here they are

1. The entries `age: ...` and `name: ...` need to be indented
2. A space was missing in the second line (`-!ruby/object:Person`) between the dash (-) and the bang (!)
3. A space is needed between the number 23 and the colon in the line `age:23`

Comment: It worked. Thanks !...How do I indent age: and name: ?

Comment: Just add couple of spaces at the beginning of each line :).